# why one of the enum's in my program has strange value 131075?

Tags: c++

I do debug this code:

```
result = conn_process(conn, 1, 0);
if (result == CG_ERR_OK) continue;
if (result == CG_ERR_TIMEOUT)
{
    break;   // i'm here!
}
```

As in debugger i'm at `break;` I assume that `result == CG_ERR_TIMEOUT` is true. In Locals I do see:

```
    result  131075  unsigned int
```

In Watch I do see:

```
    CG_ERR_TIMEOUT  error: identifier 'CG_ERR_TIMEOUT' out of scope
```

Going to definition shows me such code:

```
enum {
CG_ERR_OK = 0,
CG_ERR_INTERNAL = CG_RANGE_BEGIN,
CG_ERR_INVALIDARGUMENT,
CG_ERR_UNSUPPORTED,
CG_ERR_TIMEOUT,
CG_ERR_MORE,
CG_ERR_INCORRECTSTATE,
CG_ERR_DUPLICATEID,
CG_ERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL,
CG_ERR_OVERFLOW,
CG_ERR_UNDERFLOW,
CG_RANGE_END
};
```

So I just wonder why CG_ERR_TIMEOUT == 131075. What a strange magic number?

Comment: Clearly `conn_process` returned 131075

Comment: What is `CG_RANGE_BEGIN` ? 131075 = 0x20003 so I'm guessing that CG_RANGE_BEGIN = 0x20000 ?

Comment: ahh now i see. `#define CG_RANGE_BEGIN 0x20000` probably question can be deleted

Comment: sorry for such stupid question, it's really hard to move from c#/java to c++

Comment: and it's not convinient that VS2012 doesn't show CG_ERR_TIMEOUT value in Watch Window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because CG_RANGE_BEGIN is 131072 (which is 0x20000).

```
enum {

    CG_ERR_OK = 0,
    CG_ERR_INTERNAL = CG_RANGE_BEGIN,   // == 131072
```

From now on every enum value is the previous one plus 1:

```
    CG_ERR_INVALIDARGUMENT,             // == 131072 + 1 = 131073
    CG_ERR_UNSUPPORTED,                 // == 131073 + 1 = 131074
    CG_ERR_TIMEOUT,                     // == 131074 + 1 = 131075
    CG_ERR_MORE,                        // etc.
    CG_ERR_INCORRECTSTATE,
    CG_ERR_DUPLICATEID,
    CG_ERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL,
    CG_ERR_OVERFLOW,
    CG_ERR_UNDERFLOW,
    CG_RANGE_END

};
```